# Create a checkered board with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have a piece of code that I need to fix in order to make it render a checkered boards. Here's how it looks like now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQl9A.png

As you can see, the first cell of the second line should be blue. There's a shift. Here's my current code:

```
<div class="offer" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-repeat="offer in offers">
   <label class="ellipsis"> {{offer.name}} </label>
   <div class="offer-detail">
     <label><a href="#/offers/{{offer.id}}">Voir offre</a></label>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use ng-if inside ng-repeat but it doesn't seem to work. As I'm a complete beginner in AngularJS I might have missed something.

What I think I need is just to add the proper conditions that will reverse the colors on each row:

```
1-2-3-4 => 2 and 4 are blue (even)
5-6-7-8 => 5 and 7 are blue (odd)
9-10-11-12 => and so on...
```

EDIT:

```
#offer-list > div.odd {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#offer-list > div.even {
  background-color: rgba(0, 102, 204, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see some CSS I guess.

Comment: Will you ever have 4 cells in a row ?

Comment: Doesn't index start from 0? in this case it's doing exactly what you want: giving the same color to even and odd cells. You need to assign the CSS class according to $index+1

Comment: @enguerranws: Yes it will always have 4 columns but an undefined numbers of rows.

Comment: @enguerranws I added some CSS in my original post.

Comment: @Q3SanD Any reason why you need to do this with Angular and not just use CSS? You can do it completely with CSS, if all you're trying to get is a checkerboard background color effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple [Angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter), to check if a given index is in an even or an odd row:

```
angular.module('...')
.filter('rowType', function () {
    // Store the number of elements per row for the filter
    var elemsPerRow = 4;

    // This gets passed in the `$index` from the scope
    return function rowType(idx) {
        // Calculate the total row: Divide index by the number of elements per row
        // and use Math.floor() to get an "integer" that works with modulo (%)
        var totalRow = Math.floor(idx / elemsPerRow);
        // Return appropriate class name in each case
        return totalRow % 2 == 0 ? 'even-row' : 'odd-row';
    };
});
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt6mbhe1/1/) that demonstrates the essential code - check the console output)

and include it in the view as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="offer in offers"
  class="offer {{$index | rowType}}"
  ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
    <label class="ellipsis"> {{offer.name}} </label>
    <div class="offer-detail">
        <label><a href="#/offers/{{offer.id}}">Voir offre</a></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code is of course a bit verbose, just to make it easier to see for you what's happening. You then can set up CSS rules like this:

```
.even-row.even, .odd-row.odd { background: blue; }
.even-row.odd, .odd-row.even { background: white; }
```

**Note**: there are some other, maybe nicer ways to actually set the classes on the element, especially have a look at [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and choose what you like best.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! I just need to adapt some css (some words are blue when they should be blue and vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

If it has an undefined number of rows, I don't know if CSS can achieve that.

Here's how to do it using JS/Angular: **create a new function in your $scope, that will row-0 class on cells on odd rows and row-1 class on cells on even rows**.

```
<div class="offer {{ getRow($index) }}" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-repeat="offer in offers">
   <label class="ellipsis"> {{offer.name}} </label>
   <div class="offer-detail">
     <label><a href="#/offers/{{offer.id}}">Voir offre</a></label>
   </div>
</div>
```

In your controller :

```
var rowNb,
    classname;
$scope.getRow = function(i){

 if(i%nbCol === 0){

    rowNb++;
    if(rowNb%2 === 0) {
       classname = "odd";
      }
    else {
         classname = "even";
    }
 }
 return "row-"+classname;
}
```

*Don't know if it will work as I can't test it. But I'm pretty sure you understand the logic here : it will return row-0 on cells which compose odd rows and row-1 on even rows.*

Then, apply some CSS :

```
.offer {
   background: blue;
}
.row-0:nth-child(odd) {
    background: red;
}
.row-1:nth-child(even) {
    background: red;
}
```

Feel free to provide a live example, so I can help you to implement it.

*Note that I'm pretty sure it's dirty code, but I'm tired.*

Comment: Thank you for your help.
However I get a Error: error:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop when I try your code.

{0} $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: {1}

Comment: I also got a weird list of rows : 1-0-0-0-1-0-0-2

Comment: Can you provide a live example of this ? Sorry for that, I'm pretty tired, and when it comes to this logical stuff, I just freeze.

Comment: I edited my answer, now you should get .row-odd / .row-even. Here's a live example (pure JS, see the log) : http://jsfiddle.net/Lt6mbhe1/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried @yerforkferchips's solution below before trying your updated code and it worked. However your solution might have worked as well, it looks quite similar.

Comment: His solution looks way better I think, using a filter is a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

use css. If there are only two rows, this will work:

```
.offer:nth-child(-n+4):nth-child(odd) {
    background: #ccc;
}
.offer:nth-child(n+5):nth-child(even) {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This should work assuming .offer as another background by default.